# Connecting multiple separate monitor/mouse/keyboards to same computer within 20'

Tags: networking, multiple-desktop

I have a powerful computer which currently sits attached to my 1080p television, for playing games & watching movies from the couch (controlled by keyboard & mouse). I am setting up a work desk around 20' away with a 4k monitor. I would like this to use the same powerful computer, so I don't have to buy another. How can I set this up? Requirements:

1. Cheap (less than $100) which probably rules out a 4k KVM extender
2. Minimal number of cables running between computer and desk (at most one)
3. Easily switch between using TV and using desk (prefer not having to plug/unplug cables)
4. (Stretch goal! [Not very important, maybe impossible]) Simultaneous use of desk and television

Some possibilities I've thought of:

- Move the computer next to the desk, then use a Steam Link device for the television
- Move the computer next to the desk, then use a 1080p KVM extender for the television (would this still allow 4k video throughput for the monitor?)
- Use a thunderbolt cable to carry video & usb signals back & forth between computer and desk (was suggested on LinusTechTips forum, but specs were vague)

Also, if I go the KVM approach will it need to support HDCP in order for me to watch movies?

Comment: You're looking for Virtual Desktops, and they all have overhead, and they are typically not good at multimedia or gaming. Also, we don't offer product recommendations here at SuperUser. We are about problem solving.

Comment: Virtual desktops would require a thin client, which would almost certainly exceed the $100 limit. I'm not looking for specific product recommendations, general categories of hardware are fine.

Answer (score 1):

Problem 4k video is too high bandwidth to send over the same cable as USB.

[https://www.amazon.com/IOGEAR-4-Port-Extender-Ethernet-GUCE64/dp/B013VP3372](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B013VP3372)
[image]

Here you put 1 box each side, and connect it with a standard network cable.
USB 2.0 max, but plenty for mouse and keyboard then you just need a 20' foot hdmi or etc cable.

I know this wreck the 1 cable requirement, but its highly unrealistic.

Here is a 30ft hdmi cable for approx $20
[https://www.amazon.com/Cable-supports-FullHD-Ethernet-KabelDirekt/dp/B00DI8929Q](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00DI8929Q)

[https://www.amazon.com/Cable-Matters-Snagless-Ethernet-Black/dp/B00G9BNAKG/ref=sr_1_3?keywords=cat6+30ft&qid=1552013169&s=electronics&sr=1-3](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00G9BNAKG)

1. USB extender $54
2. 30ft hdmi    $20
3. cat 6 network cable 30 ft $9

---

$83 plus shipping and handle places it right at the $100 mark or slightly more.

Comment: It's too high-bandwidth even with thunderbolt?

Comment: @ahelwer Maybe thunderbolt might work, if you can find a USB to thunderbolt extension.  However, if they exist are probably quite expensive.

Comment: Thunderbolt optical cable https://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=9SIAEPZ7CJ1110   $275 so no, we just smashed the $100 budget.

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/Startech-Com-Console-Extender-1920X1200-Uncompressed/dp/B00P9XTWXE  This device is an eye watering $12,000

Comment: Hmmm. Maybe I'll have to keep an eye open for a 4k KVM extender on the used market.

Comment: Even this device https://www.kvm-switches-online.com/ext-uhdka-lans-rx.html is 4x your budget.